# What's the best way to represent an ERD?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, markdown

What's the best way to represent an ERD on stackoverflow?

Attempts to draw something using code syntax leaves a bit to be desired:

```
Procedure --< Order >-- Patient
                |__ Result >-- Component
```

Comment: Use a decent UML tool or such to make a picture.

Comment: It's a fair question. A fully integrated GraphViz .dot renderer would be neat. Scratch that, it'd be *awesome*. "Look, at this point your `if`s are crossing each other..."

Answer (score 3):

That's one of the cases embedded image links are more appreciated than plain (code formatted) text.

As mentioned in my comment, you should compose a diagram picture using a decent UML or otherwise diagramming tool, and post an embedded picture in your question or answer.